# Date passed to moment function increases by 1 minute

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am not a programmer and just trying my hand at something, hence please excuse if the question is stupid.

I am constructing a date using the default date function in javascript. I had thought that I will be able to do everything with it and later realised that I will have to use other libraries to achieve something easily.

While trying, I noticed this weird behaviour.

```
var d = new Date();
var DayinMS = 86400000 * 3;
var ThisDate = d.getDate();
var ThisMonth = d.getMonth();
var ThisYear = d.getFullYear();
var StartDate = Date.parse(new Date(ThisYear, ThisMonth, ThisDate, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Created a date variable in the above manner so that I have 0 in time fields. I do not know if there is a better way to do the same.

Output of StartDate is **1452105000000**.

```
var StarDate = new Date(StartDate).toString("d/MMM/yyyy");
```

Thought that I will be able to format the date by above method but no. Output of StarDate is **Thu Jan 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530**

Then searched a bit and decided to use the moment.js.

```
var newDate = moment(StartDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS');
```

And output of newDate is **07/01/2016 00:01:00**.

What I find odd is the minute counter increasing by 1. I have tested on both firefox and chrome and same result. The code above may not be good one but logically the minute counter should not increase, or I am really overlooking something?

Thanks.

Comment: The minute isn't increasing by 1, you're outputting the month.  The string passed to `format` is case sensitive, `MM` is month, `mm` is minutes.

Comment: Just figured that out a minute back while checking some other thing. :) Thanks.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Months are 0 indexed so how come "1" instead of "0"?

Comment: They're 0 indexed when coding, but when formatting for display it would be nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

Was using "MM" instead of "mm". Bad reading.